# Conversion from numpy array float32 to numpy array float64

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to implement randomforest in Python. While running the code I got this error. Although I had already converted from `float32` to `float64` using :

```
x_arr = np.array(train_df, dtype='float64')

Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\randomforest.py", line 67, in <module>     
    forest=forest.fit(x_array[0::,1::],x_array[0::,0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 212, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 398, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 54, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Please can somebody help?

Comment: What happens when you try `dtype=np.float64` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you're failing to set a float64 dtype.  The error message says:

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

So try checking for those conditions first:

```
assert not np.any(np.isnan(x_arr))
assert np.all(np.isfinite(x_arr))
assert np.all(x_arr <= finfo('float32').max)
assert np.all(x_arr >= finfo('float32').min)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got here because of the question in the title which I still feel remains unanswered.
To convert `float32` to `float64` in a `numpy.ndarray` object:

```
array32 = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=np.float32, order='F')
print("Type of an object of 'array32': " + str(type(array32[0][0])))

# Convert to float64
array64 = array32.astype(np.float64)
print("Type of an object of 'array64': " + str(type(array64[0][0])))

# Convert back to float32
array32again = array64.astype(np.float32)
print("Type of an object of 'array32again': " + str(type(array32again[0][0])))
```

Will give you:

```
Type of an object of 'array32': <class 'numpy.float32'>
Type of an object of 'array64': <class 'numpy.float64'>
Type of an object of 'array32again': <class 'numpy.float32'>
```